# What is the best mobile analytics service for iOS apps, which update downloads count live?

Tags: ios, analytics, flurry

May be this question is out of development environment. What is the best mobile analytics service for iOS apps, which update downloads count live ? Currently i am using flurry and its gives the download count like every 6 hours. Are there any quicker services ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term **Best** calls for some more explanations, as it depends on one's requirement. What are the features you need? should it be a free service? etc.

Here are some options. I am only answering this part - *Are there any quicker services ?*

1. [Bango](http://bango.com/mobileanalytics/) has mobile app analytics and it is real time (well
   according to their website).
2. **[Countly](http://count.ly/)** is another option, and it is open source and real time.
3. [mtiks](http://www.mtiks.com/) is real time.
4. [Appsflyer](http://www.appsflyer.com/) is another, but I don't think it has a free plan
5. [appinsights](http://appinsights.co.uk/) is realtime and offer a free trial period.
6. [Capptain](http://www.capptain.com/) is also real time
7. [appFigures](http://www.appfigures.com/).
8. [kontagent](http://www.kontagent.com/)

Comment: Thanks . I planned to  go ahead with countly.